# How can I fix this Wordpress Custom Gutenburg block problem with rendering once loading after it successfully saves?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, create-guten-block

As the title states I am teaching myself how to create a custom Gutenburg Block for wordpress development and I have written the following code. It functions correctly when you save, but when you reload the saved page you get console errors and it shows

> This block contains unexpected or invalid content.

When you click resolve it shows the following:

[image: Resolve block]

```js
//  Import CSS.
import './editor.scss';
import './style.scss';

const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { RichText } = wp.blockEditor
const { withColors } = wp.blockEditor
const { PanelColorSettings} = wp.blockEditor;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;


registerBlockType( 'cgb/block-my-block', {

    title: __( 'my-block - CGB Block' ), 
    icon: 'shield', 
    category: 'common', 
    keywords: [
        __( 'my-block — CGB Block' ),
        __( 'CGB Example' ),
        __( 'create-guten-block' ),
    ],
    attributes: {
        align: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'full',
        },
        link_text: {
            selector: 'a', 
            source: 'children',  
        },
        link_url: {
                selector: 'a',  
                source: 'attribute', 
                attribute: 'href', 
        },
        txtColor: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        bgcolor: {
            type: 'string'
        },
    },
    supports: {
        align:true,
        //align: ['wide','full'], // limit only to these
    },

    getEditWrapperProps() {
        return {
            'data-align': 'full',
        };
    },

    edit: ( props ) => {

        let link_text = props.attributes.link_text 
        let link_url = props.attributes.link_url 
        let txtColor = props.attributes.txtColor
        let bgColor = props.attributes.bgColor

        function onChangeContentURL ( content ) {
            props.setAttributes({link_url: content})
        }

        function onChangeContentName ( content ) {
                props.setAttributes({link_text: content})
        }    
        
        function onChangeBGColor ( content ) {
            props.setAttributes({bgColor: content})
        }  

        function onChangeColor ( content ) {
            props.setAttributes({txtColor: content})
        }    

        return (
            
            
            <div className={ props.className } style={{ backgroundColor:bgColor, color: txtColor }}>


            <InspectorControls key= { 'inspector' } >
                    <PanelBody>

                    <PanelColorSettings 
                        title={ __('Title Color', 'tar') }
                        colorSettings= { [ 
                            {
                            value: txtColor,
                            onChange: (colorValue) => onChangeColor ( colorValue ),
                            label: __('Color', 'tar'),
                            },
                         ] }
                    />

                    <PanelColorSettings 
                        title={ __('Background Color', 'tar') }
                        colorSettings= { [ 
                            {
                            value: bgColor,
                            onChange: (colorValue) => onChangeBGColor ( colorValue ),
                            label: __('Color', 'tar'),
                            },
                         ] }
                    />

                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>


                <p>Sample Link Block</p>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <RichText
                        className={props.className} // Automatic class: gutenberg-blocks-sample-block-editable
                        onChange={onChangeContentName} // onChange event callback
                        value={link_text} // Binding
                        placeholder="Name of the link"
                />
                <label>URL:</label>
                <RichText
                        format="string"             // Default is 'element'. Wouldn't work for a tag attribute
                        className={props.className} // Automatic class: gutenberg-blocks-sample-block-editable
                        onChange={onChangeContentURL} // onChange event callback
                        value={link_url} // Binding
                        placeholder="URL of the link"
                />   
                <p>— Hello from the backend.!!</p>

            </div>
        );
    },

    /**
     * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should be combined
     * into the final markup, which is then serialized by Gutenberg into post_content.
     *
     * The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Frontend HTML.
     */
    save: ( props ) => {
        let txtColor = props.attributes.txtColor
        let bgColor = props.attributes.bgColor

        return (
            <div className={ props.className } style={{ backgroundColor:bgColor, color:txtColor }} >
                <p>— Hello from the frontend.</p>
                <a href={props.attributes.link_url}>{props.attributes.link_text}</a>
                </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

The console error looks like the POST and the SAVE data are different causing the error.

The message is:

```
Block validation: Block validation failed for `cgb/block-my-block` ({name: "cgb/block-my-block", icon: {…}, attributes: {…}, keywords: Array(3), save: ƒ, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block-cgb-block-my-block alignfull" style="color:#000000"><p>— Hello from the frontend.</p><a></a></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block-cgb-block-my-block alignfull" style="background-color:#cd2653;color:#000000"><p>— Hello from the frontend.</p><a></a></div>
```

So it looks to me as if the problem is with the Save function style tag's on the root element.

```
<div className={ props.className } style={{ backgroundColor:bgColor, color:txtColor }} >
```

I have removed one style only leaving the other and it works. Putting the other back in and it breaks. Have I included this multiple style wrong? If so what is the convention for adding multiple styles that save on the root element? Also I am new and I am learning from tutorials and reading the Gutenburg github docs. If there is something rudimentary I am doing wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block validation issue is caused by a small typo where your attribute `bgcolor` (case sensitive) is called as `bgColor` in edit() and save().

Your code shows you are on the right path with creating your own custom Gutenberg block, so I'd like to share a suggestion to use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) with `props` to make your code much easier to read and maintain. Your custom `onChange` functions which just call `setAttributes()`can also be removed in favor of calling setAttributes directly, this reduces how much code you need to write and reduces the chance of typos too..

Eg:

```
//  Import CSS.
import './editor.scss';
import './style.scss';

const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { RichText } = wp.blockEditor
const { withColors } = wp.blockEditor
const { PanelColorSettings } = wp.blockEditor;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;


registerBlockType('cgb/block-my-block', {

title: __('my-block - CGB Block'),
icon: 'shield',
category: 'common',
keywords: [
    __('my-block — CGB Block'),
    __('CGB Example'),
    __('create-guten-block'),
],
attributes: {
    align: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'full',
    },
    link_text: {
        selector: 'a',
        source: 'children',
    },
    link_url: {
        selector: 'a',
        source: 'attribute',
        attribute: 'href',
    },
    txtColor: {
        type: 'string',
    },
    bgColor: {
        type: 'string',
    },
},
supports: {
    align: true,
    //align: ['wide','full'], // limit only to these
},

getEditWrapperProps() {
    return {
        'data-align': 'full',
    };
},
// Use array destructuring of props
edit: ({ attributes, className, setAttributes } = props) => {

    // Use array destructuring of the attributes
    const { link_text, link_url, txtColor, bgColor } = attributes;
    
    // Removed custom onChange functions that just call setAttributes

    return (

        <div className={className} style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor, color: txtColor }}>

            <InspectorControls key={'inspector'} >

                <PanelBody>

                    <PanelColorSettings
                        title={__('Title Color', 'tar')}
                        colorSettings={[
                            {
                                value: txtColor,
                                onChange: (colorValue) => setAttributes({ txtColor: colorValue }),
                                label: __('Color', 'tar'),
                            },
                        ]}
                    />

                    <PanelColorSettings
                        title={__('Background Color', 'tar')}
                        colorSettings={[
                            {
                                value: bgColor,
                                onChange: (colorValue) => setAttributes({ bgColor: colorValue }),
                                label: __('Color', 'tar'),
                            },
                        ]}
                    />

                </PanelBody>

            </InspectorControls>

            <p>Sample Link Block</p>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <RichText
                className={className} // Automatic class: gutenberg-blocks-sample-block-editable
                onChange={(content) => setAttributes({ link_text: content })} // onChange event callback
                value={link_text} // Binding
                placeholder="Name of the link"
            />
            <label>URL:</label>
            <RichText
                format="string" // Default is 'element'. Wouldn't work for a tag attribute
                className={className} // Automatic class: gutenberg-blocks-sample-block-editable
                onChange={(content) => setAttributes({ link_url: content })} // onChange event callback
                value={link_url} // Binding
                placeholder="URL of the link"
            />
            <p>— Hello from the backend.!!</p>

        </div>
    );
},

/**
 * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should be combined
 * into the final markup, which is then serialized by Gutenberg into post_content.
 *
 * The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
 *
 * @param {Object} props Props.
 * @returns {Mixed} JSX Frontend HTML.
 */
// Use array destructuring of props
save: ({ attributes, className } = props) => {

    // Use array destructuring of the attributes
    const { txtColor, bgColor, link_url, link_text } = attributes;

    return (
        <div className={className} style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor, color: txtColor }}>
            <p>— Hello from the frontend.</p>
            <a href={link_url}>{link_text}</a>
        </div >
    );
},
});
```

Comment: Thank you after applying your suggestions the code works perfectly. I also was looking at the code I had and was thinking that it was messy. You hit the nail on the head when you suggested array/object destructuring. For some reason I find this line    edit: ({ attributes, className, setAttributes } = props) => { ... Quite hard to understand could you please explain. Is this adding attributes, className and setAttributes avaiable to props directly?